# many attributes in manyTomanyField does not have a attribute called .all()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have created a model named Flight which is connected to another model named Passengers

`flights = models.ManyToManyField(Flight, blank=True, related_name="passengers")`

i tried to use `Passengers = Flight.Passengers.all()` it throws an error saying that

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<console>", line 1, in <module> AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

need help with it!

i want only the realted fields from flight and passengers into my html but it throw an error whenever i try to access using `Flight.Passengers.all()` and `Flight.Passengers.get()`

it can be bypass using `Passengers.objects.all()` but i don't need that otherwise there will be no relation between my databases!

Answer (score 0):

That makes perfect sense, the `related_name` works with a `Flight` *object*, not the `Flight` *class*, what would that even mean?

You thus fetch a `Flight` object:

```
my_flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=1)  # Flight object with pk=1
```

and then you get the passengers of the `my_flight` with:

```
my_flight.passengers.all()
```

It does not work with the `Flight` *class*, the only sensical response for that would be returning all `Passenger`s that have at least *one* flight. You can do that with:

```
# Passengers linked to at least one Flight
Passenger.objects.filter(flights__isnull=False).distinct()
```